# R list - expand vector element to list elements with the same name

Tags: r, purrr

I wonder if there is a shorter way of performing the following transformation:

```r
params <- list(A = 1, B = c(1, 2))  #   ->   list(A = 1, B = 1, B = 2)
purrr::lmap(params,
  ~ purrr::set_names(as.list(.x[[1]]),
                     rep(names(.x), length(.x[[1]])))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option where we `unlist` the 'params' `list`,  then  convert  each element to a list element with `as.list` while setting the `names` of the `list` with the `rep`licated `names` of 'params' based on the `lengths` of the original `list`

```
setNames(as.list(unlist(params)), rep(names(params), lengths(params)))
```

---

Or with `stack/deframe`

```
library(tibble)
as.list(deframe(stack(params)[2:1]))
```